# Page Numbering in MS-Word using Roman numerals

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am trying to use Roman numerals for page numbering in MS-Word where a hyphen appears before and after the Roman numeral. It should appear like this -I-, -II-, -III- , ....in the page footer. In the existing Ms-Word formats, the Roman numerals are available only in this format: I, II, III... Can anyone help with how to make page numbers like this: -I-, -II-, -III- ....

Comment: You may also want to look at Numbering Front Matter by Suzanne Barnhill, Word MVP. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it manually in combination with page numbers.

- Open your Word document
- Open the footer
- From the main menu ribbon Insert > Page Number > Format Page Numbers
- Select numer Format I, II, III, ...
- OK
- Click before the pabe number and enter `-`  (hyphen, space)
- Click after the page page number and enter  `-` (space, hyphen)
- Close the footer

[image]

[image]

Maybe useful to show paragraph marks and other hidden formatting symbols. This is especially useful for advanced layout tasks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer solved my question.